Summing a summarised virtual table
I am trying to report on customer targets over time. Base data is a customer list and an audit table of changes made to the target by customer.
So I have created a measure that converts these sporadically timed audits to a running total:
RunningTarget = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Target Changes'[TargetTo]),
        LASTNONBLANK(
            DATESBETWEEN(Calendar[Date], BLANK(), LASTDATE(Calendar[Date])),
            CALCULATE(COUNT('Target Changes'[TargetTo]))
        )
    )

Which works great for a single customer - I can map these changes on a chart over time. But I now need to roll it up to various parent levels (region, sales rep, etc), and am struggling to get a sum of this measure per day across multiple (or all) customers.
I have created a measure which builds a virtual table of all dates and all customers and the running target for each per day, but using SUMX to return an overall total per day isn't doing what I want and I can't see why.
TargetTotal = 
VAR TargetTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            VALUES(Calendar[Date]), 
            VALUES('Target Changes'[CustomerID])
        ), 
        "Target", [RunningTarget]
    )
RETURN 
    SUMX(
        GROUPBY(
            TargetTable,
            [Date],
            "SummedTarget", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [Target])
        ), 
        [SummedTarget]
    )

I have tested the TargetTable and GROUPBY in calculated tables and they appear to be returning what I'm expecting [see edit below], but this measure is only returning a number for the dates where there was an audit change. What have I done wrong?
Edit:
Just to clarify/show the testing I have done in calculated tables:
TargetTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            VALUES(Calendar[Date]), 
            VALUES('Target Changes'[CustomerID])
        ), 
        "Target", [RunningTarget]
    )

Gives the (expected) result:



Date
CustomerID
Target




01/01/2024
1
£10,000


02/01/2024
1
£10,000


03/01/2024
1
£25,000


04/01/2024
1
£25,000


05/01/2024
1
£25,000


etc




01/01/2024
2
£15,000


02/01/2024
2
£15,000


03/01/2024
2
£15,000


04/01/2024
2
£15,000


05/01/2024
2
£10,000


etc





And then:
SummedTargetTotal = 
VAR TargetTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            VALUES(Calendar[Date]), 
            VALUES('Target Changes'[CustomerID])
        ), 
        "Target", [RunningTarget]
    )
RETURN 
    GROUPBY(
        TargetTable,
        [Date],
        "SummedTarget", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [Target])
    ), 

Returns (also as expected):



Date
SummedTarget




01/01/2024
£25,000


02/01/2024
£25,000


03/01/2024
£40,000


04/01/2024
£40,000


05/01/2024
£35,000


etc




So, both are returning rows for all dates with correct summing, so I don't understand why the measure is only returning rows for dates where there was an audit change.
Incidentally, I could solve this by just using the calculated tables, but 1. they are massive and slow (in this case at least), and 2. this is being built on an existing dataset that I don't own.

Solved this. Changed the cross join to look at the customer table instead of the audit table (even though the distinct list of Customer ID's are identical in each table...). It must have somehow been filtering the results, although I didn't think that's how CROSSJOIN worked. Anyway, working code is now:
TargetTotal = 
VAR TargetTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            VALUES(Calendar[Date]), 
            VALUES('Customers'[CustomerID])
        ), 
        "Target", [RunningTarget]
    )
RETURN 
    SUMX(
        GROUPBY(
            TargetTable,
            [Date],
            "SummedTarget", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [Target])
        ), 
        [SummedTarget]
    )


The problem might be that your  measure only returns values for dates where there was an audit change, so the final result only sums those specific dates rather than all dates in the range :
TargetTotal = 
VAR TargetTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            VALUES(Calendar[Date]), 
            VALUES('Target Changes'[CustomerID])
        ), 
        "Target", 
        CALCULATE([RunningTarget], 
            FILTER(ALL('Target Changes'[CustomerID]), 
            'Target Changes'[CustomerID] = EARLIER('Target Changes'[CustomerID])))
    )
RETURN 
    SUMX(
        VALUES(Calendar[Date]), 
        SUMX(
            FILTER(TargetTable, [Date] = EARLIER(Calendar[Date])), 
            [Target]
        )
    )

